# How can i write all the procedure that happens in euclidean algorithm for fiding GCD in C#?

Tags: c#

I have this

```
public int GCD(int a, int b)
{
    while (a != 0 && b != 0)
    {
        if (a > b)
            a %= b;
        else
            b %= a;
    }

    if (a == 0)
        return b;
    else
        return a;
}
```

But I want all the procedure like `892=2*438+16` then `438=27*16+6` and so on.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what is being asked here.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want to add something like:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}*{2}+{3}",a,a/b,b,a%b)
```

before `a %= b;` and the same thing with swapped `a` and `b` before  `b %= a;`